# How to deploy a simple python webserver in a right way?

Tags: python, web-deployment, web.py

I'm pretty new to python. I've started to learn a few lesssons, and for now, I'm trying to deploy a simple webserver based on web.py. Can someone help me and give an answer to these two questions:

1. I installed the web.py in `/home/.../public_html/cgi-bin/lib/python/web` catalog. `public_html` - the catalog from which my website starts. So What should I write in python scripts in top?

   I mean, if I write just `import web` than script works fine only in `/public_html/cgi-bin/lib/python/` catalog. Can I put the script in a other catalog, can't I? What should I write in import section in that case?
2. According to webpy.org a simple "Hello world" web app look like:

   ```
   import web

   urls = (
       '/(.*)', 'hello'
   )
   app = web.application(urls, globals())

   class hello:        
       def GET(self, name):
           if not name: 
               name = 'World'
           return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run()
   ```

When i run it, webserver takes default port as `8080`. How to change it to standard 80, that will make my website available by url `http://website.com`?

P.S. It seems to me that formatting doesn't works fine on stackoverflow. Sorry for that.

Comment: You should read [this entry](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache) in the web.py manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your second question: try to override run.

```
import web

class MyApplication(web.application):
    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('0.0.0.0', port))

urls = (
   '/(.*)', 'hello'
)

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApplication(urls, globals())
    app.run(port=8888)
```

Comment: Thanks for example! But in that case I can't run it on 80 port? I have to go on http://website.com:8888/

Comment: You just need modify port: app.run(port=80)